# Is this spider as dangerous as it looks?

Tags: identification, insects

It is about a little more than an inch (3cm) from tip to tip.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What country are you in? There are similar looking species native to Europe and the USA, some more venomous than others - but they aren't aggressive, and won't kill you even if you get bitten unless you have problems with your immune system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a common garden spider to me. Perhaps the [Banded Garden Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_trifasciata) or [Wasp Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_bruennichi). These are not dangerous to you. They are your friends. I keep mine on my raspberry plant so they can eat those pesky [Japanese beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_beetle).